# Tracing migrated questions

Tags: discussion, migration

If a question is migrated from ELU, is there anything left behind that might still direct the attention of our users to that question? For example, is there a list of migrated questions?

I am a bit curious because, as far as I can see, the decision to migrate seems to be up to five or so ELU users, however, once it happens, the question seems to disappear from here so latecomers have no access to it. That seems to make migration hardly revocable, although (as I said) it is decided by only a few users.

Comment: I don't know if this link is visible to you, maybe you need to have 10K, but in the review queues there is an *alcove* where you can see which posts migrated to where and which emigrated to EL&U http://english.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks. No, I cannot see that part, it does need 10K.

Comment: I think that there is a good portion of the community that doesn't understand that migration is a bigger deal than closing for exactly this reason. You point out why even though a question might be accepted by another site, it may not be a good idea to let it go so easily. Migration in my opinion should be much more rare than it is. [A question cannot be off-topic on one site for no other reason than that it fits better on another](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4249/80039)

Comment: @ColleenV I beg to differ. There should be far more migration than now as learners are flooding this site for a quick fix for very basic questions after finding ELU Googling some words or phrases. Migration should be considered as a way of introducing ELL to learners, not a way of dumping cXXX to ELL. Those learners will more likely get a good answer on ELL than ELU and why do you care so much about the quality of a questions being migrated? You can close it on ELL if you find it off-topic. If a user is willing to ask another question after migration, ELL should be a site, not ELU.

Comment: @Rathony Of course we should be concerned about the quality of migrated questions. If they are good and on-topic here, they should not be migrated. And I am sceptical about using migration as a means of education newcomers about where they should ask their next question.

Comment: @anemone I know what you mean, but we don't migrate good and on-topic questions here. Everyone has their own opinion on that. It has been discussed extensively and I am saying I don't see any harm done to Stack Exchange by migrating more questions. That's all.

Comment: @Rathony You don't have to migrate a question to ELL to direct a learner to ELL. Frankly for low-effort questions, I think it's better to just close it and send them over because they will need to create an ELL account to post their question. A lot of learners get really confused when they have a question on a different site, but not an account there.

Comment: @ColleenV I completely stopped voting for migration a few months ago. You don't have to worry about it. For technical issues like creating an  account on ELL, some users don't even register on ELU to ask a question,. I don't see how it is relevant to the migration issue.

Answer (score 2):

> ...as far as I can see, the decision to migrate seems to be up to five
>   or so ELU users...

It takes five close-votes to put a question on hold unless a moderator is involved with a single hammer. However, it doesn't necessarily mean it takes all five close-votes to migrate it. Sometimes, it takes only 3 close-votes to migrate when the other two votes are cast for other reasons such as 'general reference' or 'proof-reading'.

> Is there a list of migrated questions?

You can search using [migrated:1](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=migrated%3a1) to see the list of questions migrated to and from ELU.

When you reach [10,000 reputation points](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you will be able to use the [moderator tool > review > migrated](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away).

> That seems to make migration hardly revocable, although (as I said) it
>   is decided by only a few users.

If a question is closed on the site to which it was migrated, the question will return to ELU.

I have seen one case where @deadrat posted a request on ELL Meta to migrate a question back to ELU by closing the question on ELL. It was done within an hour or so and I don't think "migration" is hardly revocable even though it will take some time and efforts to do that. If it is coordinated well between moderators of each site, it would be even faster and easier.

There are many questions related with ["migration to ELL"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=migration+to+ELL) which might interest you.

Comment: Thank you for the search term! I had no idea.

Comment: @anemone Always my pleasure. Glad it helped!

Comment: What I meant by "hardly revocable" is the existing imbalance between closure mechanism (once a question is marked for closure, it is highlighted for all 3K users to see as a candidate for closure) and the mechanism that can theoretically revoke migration -- the visibility of migrated questions is very low.

Comment: @anemone When a question is voted to be **put on hold** by one user for whatever reason, other users have all the choices, "to leave it open", "close as XYZ", "Close for migration". Why do you think we need a mechnism to revoke migration? You don't have to agree to the migration. But, unfortunately you have only one vote and so do I. The majority wins.

Comment: All this time, I am talking about visibility here. Once a question is migrated, it is barely visible to users on this site. (Unlike questions that are put on hold, for example.) There does not seem to be a grace period of several days or anything like that.

Comment: @anemonen One thing you need to note is many closed questions are deleted by the system and votes. But migrated questions are not. They are better treated than a majority of closed questions. Now, why do you need to see them? Why do we need a grace period when you can find it if you want? Once the question is migrated, unless it is returned and reopened, we don't need it. Members decided that the question doesn't contribute anything to ELU. That's why they are migrated.